# Split string in a csv python

Tags: python, string, csv, split

Every row of my list goes like this:

```
[(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292'])]
```

and I want it to print just the name, in this case `Vicky`. The code I use is this

```
for x in numbers:  
    r=str(x)  
    d1= r.split(',')  
    print ('D1', d1)
```

and it prints this:

```
['[(21', " ['Rodriguez'", " 'Lara'", " 'Vicky'", " '55302292'])]"]
```

Comment: What has all this to do with CSV files though? Yes, Python list and tuple objects use commas in the syntax to delimit distinct values, but that doesn't make them CSVs. :-)

Comment: if all of them have same  structure, just `[(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292'])][0][1][2]` :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't turn your perfectly good list into a string! just use indexing:

```
x[0][1][2]
```

To illustrate what this does:

```
>>> x = [(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292'])]
>>> x[0]
(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292'])
>>> x[0][1]
['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292']
>>> x[0][1][2]
'Vicky'
```

Each additional subscription (`[...]`) drills deeper into the nested structure; `x[0]` extracts the tuple from the list; `x[0][1]` then accesses the list value in that tuple (`x[0][0]` would give you `21`), and `x[0][1][2]` give you back `'Vicky'`, the third element in that nested list.

Answer (score 3):

Get the list first, then extract data from it

```
>>> list = [(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292'])]
>>> names = list[0][1] 
>>> names
['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292']
>>> names[2]
Vicky
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over your list, while unpacking a tuple in each iteration. This would make it slightly more clean/readable.

```
>>> x = [(21, ['Rodriguez', 'Lara', 'Vicky', '55302292']), (22, ['Micheal', 'Jackson', 'John', '66302292'])]
>>> for age, details in x:
...     print details[2]
... 
Vicky
John
```

Comment: Maybe you could accompany your answer with some text that explains it :) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in numbers:
  r=str(x)
  a=r.split(',')
  print (a[3].strip("' "))
```